# Doubt on Morrey spaces of measures according to T. Giga and Y. Miyakawa

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, fluid-dynamics

I'm reading *'Navier-Stokes flow in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with measures as initial vorticity and Morrey spaces'* (a paper of Giga and Miyakawa) but there is something that I don't understand about the definition of Morrey spaces they give.

They introduce them (for each $1\leq p\leq \infty$) as the spaces of Radon signed measures $\mu$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$ verifying:

$$\Vert \mu\Vert_p:=\sup\limits_{x\in \mathbb{R}^N,r>0} r^{-\frac{N}{p'}}\cdot \vert\mu\vert(B(x,r))<\infty$$

They proof that $\Vert \cdot \Vert_p$ is a Banach norm, but I don't understand how could one sum two Radon signed measure without having problems at computing $+\infty-\infty$. Notice that we are NOT asuming $\mu$ to have finite total variation.

Could anyone help me?
Thanks.

PD: Sorry for my English.

Comment: The addition operation on the space of signed measures is really only a partial binary operation, exactly to avoid the issue of $\infty - \infty$. I am not familiar with the work of Giga and Miyakawa, but they probably just avoid the issue entirely. Namely, by considering the triangle inequality $\|x +y\| \le \|x\|+\|y\|$ only when the sum $x+y$ is well-defined.

Comment: Thak you very much. I thought they were using an implicit construction of addition by means of inner regularity but your answer makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what one means by a **signed** Radon measure. In the context of non-compact spaces it does not really make sense to require that it is well-defined on the whole space, so that I am pretty sure that what they mean by a signed Radon measure $\mu$ is just $\mu=\mu_+-\mu_-$, where $\mu_{\pm}$ are two positive (not necessarily finite) Radon measures. Then $\mu$ makes sense on any compact subspace, whereas under additional growth assumptions on $\mu$ (like the one made in the quoted paper) one can make integrals against $\mu$ well-defined for certain functions with non-compact support as well.

Comment: I agree with you. I'm reading about related topic in other references just know and it seems that they only consider meausures locally (defined for bounded Borel sets). So, what you mean is that the space of signed Radon measures they are problably considerying is kind of the vector space of formal sums $\alpha\cdot \mu+\beta\cdot \mu$ with $\mu,\nu$ positive Radon measures, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: I was afraid of changing the standard definition because I wanted to go on seeing this measures as distributions in the same way we see locally finite borel measures, but there is no problem. The only problem I have, if we use $\mathcal{M}^p$ for noting this subspace is to describe in an easy way the intersection $L^1_{loc}\cap \mathcal{M}^p$ (in the sense of distributions). Such functions $f$ verify: $$\int f\cdot\varphi \,dx=\int \phi \,d\mu^+ +\int \phi \,d\mu^-$$ for every $\varphi\in C^{\infty}_c$ and certain $\mu^+,\mu^-$ positive Radon measures

Comment: I say "problems" because $\mu^+,\mu^-$ seem to be too arbitrary. But perhaps there are not better descriptions. I'll go on reading. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry for my typing mistakes. I wanted to write: $$\int f\cdot \varphi\,dx=\int \varphi\,d\mu^+-\int \varphi \,d\mu^-$$

Comment: No - $\mu_+$ and $\mu_-$ are not arbitrary! They are from the Hahn decomposition (be it in the space of general measures or in the space of densities of absolutely continuous measures, i.e., in $L^1$), so that they have to be mutually singular.

Comment: Hahn decomposition theorem states that each signed measure is $\mu=\mu^+-\mu^-$ with $\mu^+,\mu^-$ mutually singular positive measures, one of them is finite. But the space of signed measures of my first comment was: $$\{\mu-\nu:\mu,\nu\mbox{ are positive measures}\}$$ (with formal sums). I was not asuming the Hahn decomposition property on it and it can't be deduced from definition because elements of this space aren't real measures (only formal expresions designed for working locally on compacts). If I want this property I have to asume it in the definition.

Comment: However, I think this space is too artifitial and it's better to work with signed Radon measures locally. So, Hahn decomposition theorem holds as you has pointed out